# discord.py как сделать чтобы бот отправил сообщение в нужный мне канал?

Tags: python, discord.py, modal

У меня возникла проблема с отправкой сообщения в нужный мне канал.
Я перепробовал всё что знал. Помогите пожалуйста!

Вот код:

```py
class EveModal(discord.ui.Modal, title = "Заявка на пост ивентера!"):
    name = discord.ui.TextInput(label = "Имя?")
    age = discord.ui.TextInput(label = "Возвраст?")
    sentry = discord.ui.TextInput(label = "Часовой пояс от мск?")
    whyou = discord.ui.TextInput(label = "Почему именно вы?", style = discord.TextStyle.paragraph)
    yourslf = discord.ui.TextInput(label = "Немного о себе", style = discord.TextStyle.paragraph)
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        channel = client.get_channel('1060262034496815176')
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Заявка на Eventer", description = f"Имя: {self.name}\nВозвраст: {self.age}\nЧасовой поис: {self.sentry}\nПочему именно вы: {self.whyou}\nНемного о себе")
        await channel.send(f"Имя: {self.name}\nВозвраст: {self.age}\nЧасовой поис: {self.sentry}\nПочему именно вы: {self.whyou}\nНемного о себе")
```

Данный код работает, но после нажатия этой кнопки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

бот выдает не выдает ошибку и нечего не отправляет!

Answer (score 0):

Не отправляется, потому что ты написал channel.send
Нужно написать ctx.send(ctx.reply)